# The 'name' in the add_series in the chart does not work in this format

Tags: python-3.x, xlsxwriter

Taking the example from here: http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/example_chart_line.html
The below code does not work. ( I removed the second add_series)

```
import xlsxwriter

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('chart_line.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet("Example Data")
bold = workbook.add_format({'bold': 1})

# Add the worksheet data that the charts will refer to.
headings = ['Number', 'Batch 1', 'Batch 2']
data = [
    [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
    [10, 40, 50, 20, 10, 50],
    [30, 60, 70, 50, 40, 30],
]

worksheet.write_row('A1', headings, bold)
worksheet.write_column('A2', data[0])
worksheet.write_column('B2', data[1])
worksheet.write_column('C2', data[2])

# Create a new chart object. In this case an embedded chart.
chart1 = workbook.add_chart({'type': 'line'})

# Configure the first series.
chart1.add_series({
    'name':       '=Example Data!$B$1',
    'categories': '=Example Data!$A$2:$A$7',
    'values':     '=Example Data!$B$2:$B$7',
})

# Add a chart title and some axis labels.
chart1.set_title ({'name': 'Results of sample analysis'})
chart1.set_x_axis({'name': 'Test number'})
chart1.set_y_axis({'name': 'Sample length (mm)'})

# Set an Excel chart style. Colors with white outline and shadow.
chart1.set_style(10)

# Insert the chart into the worksheet (with an offset).
worksheet.insert_chart('D2', chart1, {'x_offset': 25, 'y_offset': 10})


workbook.close()
```

Then the 'name' field does not seem to work and it shows as `series1` whereas it should have been `Batch1`.
[image]

Am I missing something or is this a bug?

Comment: It works in the example that you linked to, as shown by the screenshot. Could you show a complete example where it doesn't work.

Comment: Sorry, I wasnt clear. It works in the example that I have linked to. But in the code I pasted, it doesnt work.It does not show `Batch1` instead shows `series1`. Edited the question.

Answer (score 3):

I ran your (unedited) sample program and I get the expected output, i.e., a series name of `Batch1` instead of `Series1`:

[image]

I'd suggest making sure that you have an updated version of XlsxWriter. Also, check the output in Excel (sometimes OpenOffice or Libreoffice display charts differenly).

Comment: I have edited the question. Can you try with this? Note I have added sheet name now

Comment: You need to quote the sheet name in the formula like this "='Example Data'!$B$1" since it contains spaces. Excel requires this. The XlsxWriter list methods do the quoting automatically for you but if you are supplying the string you need to ensure the formula is valid.

Comment: Ahh I see . I missed that one. Thanks @jmcnamara

Comment: In order to (hopefully) avoid this type of error in the future I've added a warning to the module that for the sample code would raise a warning like this: `UserWarning: Sheetname in '=Example Data!$B$2:$B$7' contains spaces but isn't quoted. This may cause errors in Excel.`

Comment: Having a space in the name of a sheet, gives me an error. However, having dash line '-' in the name of a sheet runs without any errors, but the categories do not appear.